# perf show events per elf-section

Tags: linux, elf, perf

Is there a way to get `perf report` (or any other `perf` analysis tool) to display even counts by elf-section?

For example standard `perf record echo "hi"; perf report` results in:

```
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object     Symbol                
# ........  .......  ................  ......................
#
    20.62%  echo     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaafa7fbb
    20.59%  echo     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa88996a
    18.12%  echo     libc.so.6         [.] __GI___getrandom
    17.68%  echo     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa52af74
    16.52%  echo     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa8a5d57
     5.51%  echo     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaafb6c1c
     0.83%  perf-ex  [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaafb10f0
     0.11%  perf-ex  [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa249286
     0.02%  perf-ex  [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa210b39
     0.00%  perf-ex  [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa296106
     0.00%  perf-ex  [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffaa296104
```

Instead of `Symbol` being the function (or address if symbol resolution fails), is there a way to just get it to be the elf section (so maybe `.text` or `.text.<arbitrary-other-section>`.

?

Edit:
The motivation is to get reliable symbol information when compiling with `-ffunction-sections`.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to just get it to be the elf section (so maybe `.text` or ...

I doubt such an option exists -- it seems a very strange requirement (http://xyproblem.info may be applicable here).

`perf` is an open-source program; you could built a new copy which resolves addresses to section names instead of symbol names.

---

An easier solution is probably to use `perf script -D`, which produces output similar to:

```
655100227667001 0x4d0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP2 991807/991807: [0x557bfc80c000(0x1000) @ 0x1000 fe:00 22546274 180651332]: r-xp /tmp/a.out
...
655100231257619 0x918 [0x28]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 991807/991807: 0x557bfc80c38d period: 1965769 addr: 0
...
           a.out 991807 655100.228914:    2945520 cycles:      557bfc80c38d MyClass::~MyClass+0x19 (/tmp/a.out)
...
           a.out 991807 655100.238353:    1115949 cycles:      557bfc80c38d MyClass::~MyClass+0x19 (/tmp/a.out)
...
```

You can use the `PERF_RECORD_MMAP2` to figure out where in memory sections of interest are, and then translate the addresses from `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` records into section names (and discard symbol names).

---

Found an even easier solution.

Suppose you have `a.out`, which is an unstripped binary. `perf record ./a.out; perf report` produces a "normal" report:

```
  99.88%  a.out    a.out                 [.] MyClass::~MyClass
   0.03%  a.out    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  [.] _dl_relocate_object
   0.02%  a.out    [unknown]             [k] 0xffffffffb005b01b
...
```

Let's run a few commands:

```
mv a.out a.out.orig
strip a.out.orig -o a.out.stripped
cp a.out.stripped a.out
perf report
```

Now the report looks like this:

```
  60.44%  a.out    a.out                 [.] 0x000000000000138d
  21.88%  a.out    a.out                 [.] 0x0000000000001389
  17.56%  a.out    a.out                 [.] 0x0000000000001391
   0.03%  a.out    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  [.] _dl_relocate_object
...
```

Not quite what you wanted. But let's add a symbol at the start of `.text`:

```
objcopy a.out.stripped  a.out  --add-symbol .text=.text:0x0,function,global
```

Now running `perf report` produces:

```
  99.88%  a.out    a.out                 [.] .text
   0.03%  a.out    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  [.] _dl_relocate_object
```

which is *exactly* what you wanted (you can add more symbols for other sections of interest).

Comment: I want to be able to get reliable per-function profile data without omitting the frame-pointer. Compiling with `-ffunction-sections` gives all the information for function -> event w.o the overhead. Editted question to reflect that.

Comment: @Noah Now your question makes even _less_ sense -- frame pointers have ~nothing to do with `perf` (unless you are recordig call stack with the `-g` flag). With `-ffunction-sections` you _already_ have 1:1 relationship between function name and section name, so you should already have the output you desire.

Comment: You're right the frame-pointer stuff isn't really a big deal. But for example perf display interrupts as having happened in `0xffffffffaafa7fbb`, is there a way to go from runtime actual address to elf section?

Comment: @Noah: That's a kernel address.  Are you planning to rebuild your kernel with `-ffunction-sections`?  Why not just build a non-stripped kernel so you have symbols per function, and/or put the kernel symbol table somewhere perf can find it?